# Need some idea how i can write shell script for below requirement

Tags: shell-script

Write a bash script for below :

We have a requirement to monitor and the track the changes of all the mounts points on linux server. If there are any changes on mount point, these should get alerted to IT team via email. Also, the script should be able to provide the space utilization of the respective mount point where there is an issue.
i.e example alert :
1. Changes detected on mount point /mnt/app1, it is newly added mount point with current usage of 90 GB out of allocated 200GB
1. Changes detected on mount point /mnt/app0, it was mounted earlier however it is not mounted now

Comment: This is a Unix group, not order-my-script site. Please detail what you have done and what can we explain to you.

Answer (score 1):

Every *n* seconds:

1. Make a list of mounted mount points with their disk usage:

   ```
   LC_ALL=C df -h $(
     LC_ALL=C mount | 
     grep '^/\S\+ on \S\+' |
     sed -Ee 's/^\S+\s+on\s+(\S+).*/\1/'
   ) | tail -n +2
   ```

   (Don't use the example code in production as is; you will of course want to sanitize the list of mounted mount points.)
2. Compare the current list with the previous list, for example using `diff`.
3. If there are differences, interpret them and generate the nice e-mails.
4. Replace the old list with the current list.